# OpenCV Mat types for float array array operations

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCv for Java.
I'm trying to perform some operations on images in an efficient way, so using divide and multiply instead of cycle trough rows and cols. Unluckily any assignment to my Mat is getting truncated/rounded. I'm clearly missing some important concept here.

sample code (Groovy actually)

```
Mat mat = getMat(filename)
Mat dst = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_64FC3)
mat.convertTo(dst, -1)
dst.put(1,1,[180.5,180.5,180.5] as double[])
println "pix:" + dst.get(1,1)
Core.divide(dst, new Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), dst)
println "divided 255:" + dst.get(1,1)
```

Would expect/need:

```
pix:[180.5, 180.5, 180.5]
divided 255:[0.7, 0.7, 0.7]
```

gets instead:

```
pix:[180.0, 180.0, 180.0]
divided 255:[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

**What am I missing?**
Is there a CvType that can contain actual floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change second parameter of mat.convertTo from -1 to CvType.CV_64FC3.

From documentation of convertTo method parameters:

convertTo(Mat m, int rtype)

m - Destination matrix. If it does not have a proper size or type before the operation, it is reallocated.

**rtype** - Desired destination matrix type or, rather, the depth since the number of channels are the same as the source has. **If rtype is negative, the destination matrix will have the same type as the source.**

So as you can see, you are converting your image to the same type.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really don't know how I missed this